# Kivy dealing with multiple Button Events

Tags: python, oop, button, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy.

I am trying to build a simple memory game in which the user will have to remember a sequence of button press. The user will have to remember the sequence shown in the screen and repeat it by pressing the different buttons

**The Problem ?**

I don't know how to make my program repeat a given sequence of button presses. In my code, my program on repeat the last element of the sequence x times

I have read the Clock documentation and the button documentation but it did not solve my issue

**My python code**

```
def start_game_round(self):
    buttons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3', 'button4']
    sequence = ['2', '2', '1']

    time = 0
    for elm in sequence:
        b = "button" + elm
        self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.ids['button' + elm].trigger_action(0.5), 0.5 + time)
        time += 1
```

**The kivy file**

```
<MyMemoryGame>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size: root.width * 2 / 3, root.height
        padding: 50, 50
        spacing: 10, 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size



        Button:
            id: button1
        Button:
            id: button2
        Button:
            id: button3
        Button:
            id: button4
    GridLayout:
        rows:3
        size: root.width / 3, root.height
        pos: root.width * 2/ 3, 0
        padding: 50, 50
        spacing: 10, 10
        Label:
            text: 'Score'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Button:
         
            text: 'Next Round !'
            on_press: root.start_game_round()
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start_game_round()` will work if you use `partial` to freeze the inputs to your `lambda` function:

```
def start_game_round(self):
    buttons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3', 'button4']
    sequence = ['2', '2', '1']

    time = 0
    for elm in sequence:
        b = "button" + elm
        self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_once(partial(lambda x,dt: self.ids[x].trigger_action(0.5), b), 0.5 + time)
        time += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*As i understand, you're trying to make mini memory game.And you want to check buttons sequence with your programmed sequence.I made mini game for you. I hope it helps you.*

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from random import randint,random
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class GamePage(Screen):
    mylayout = ObjectProperty()
    score_label= ObjectProperty()
    sequence = []
    check_sequ = 0
    score = NumericProperty(0)
    button_widget_list = []
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_random_sequence)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_buts)
    def create_random_sequence(self,*args):
        self.sequence = []
        for i in range(3):
            value = randint(0,4)
            while value in self.sequence:
                value = randint(0,4)
            self.sequence.append(value)
        print(self.sequence)
    def create_buts(self,*args):
        for i in range(5):
            but = Button(text='Button' + str(i + 1))
            but.bind(on_release=self.is_but_correct)
            self.button_widget_list.append(but)
            self.mylayout.add_widget(but)
    def is_but_correct(self,but):
        for i in range(5):
            if but == self.button_widget_list[i]:
                if i == self.sequence[self.check_sequ]: #If user clicked correct sequ button:
                    self.button_widget_list[i].background_color = [random(),random(),random(),.75]
                    self.check_sequ += 1
                    self.score += 100
                    if self.check_sequ == 3:
                        self.check_sequ = 0
                        self.score_label.text = 'Congratulations'
                        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_new,2)
                else:
                    if self.score > 0:
                        self.score -= 25
                    self.reset_buttons()
                    self.check_sequ = 0
                break
    def reset_buttons(self,*args):
        for but in self.button_widget_list:
            but.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        self.score_label.text = str(self.score)
    def create_new(self,*args):
        self.create_random_sequence()
        self.reset_buttons()
class test(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

**test.kv:**

```
<SM>:
    GamePage:
        name: 'gamepagename'
<GamePage>:
    mylayout:mylayout
    score_label:score_label
    BoxLayout:
        id: mylayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: score_label
            text: 'Score : '+ str(root.score)
```